# how to find foreign key mapping?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a Database in MS SQL Server 2008 .

It has a table  BRANCH.

this table has a column BRANCH_ID. This is a foreign key to another table.

I want to find to which table this foreign key is mapped.   How do I find it ?

(I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to use the UI, just find the table in the object browser, expand it, then expand keys and then right click and select modify on the key you are interested in. Then you can check under "Table and column specifications" and it will tell you the tables that are involved (you will be interested in the "primary key" table).

If you want to query for it, you can use the `sys.foreign_keys` view and `sys.foreign_key_columns` view to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks Darren ...this helped. how to choose the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008, edit the table indexes and you will find the info.